# Using seqinr package in R to count bases of an DNA sequence

Tags: r

I have an array which was extracted from a fasta file

```
> dat
  [1] "t" "a" "t" "t" "t" "a" "c" "c" "g" "a" "c" "g" "a" "a" "a" "t" "t" "a" "a" "t" "a" "c" "c" "a" "t" "c" "a" "g" "g" "g" "t" "a" "t"
  [34] "t" "a" "a" "g" "a" "t" "g" "c" "t" "a" "c" "c" "a" "a" "c" "g" "t" "g" "g" "t" "a" "t" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "t" "g" "t" "g" "c" "c"
  [67] "c" "a" "a" "c" "c" "g" "c" "g" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "g" "a" "a" "a" "g" "t" "g" "g" "t" "a" "t" "a" "t" "a" "g" "g" "a" "a" "a" "a"
```

The sequence is much longer but for that is unimportant I wish to break up the first 100000 characters in this array into intervals of length 1000 and count the number of "g" bases in each interval. So far I've tried:

```
library(seqinr)
intervals = 1000*(0:99)
g_count = count(dat[intervals+1:intervals+1000], 1)[["g"]]
```

but this returns the error: `numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used`
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count number of 'g' in each interval you could use this base R approach :

```
n <- 1000
result <- tapply(dat, ceiling(seq_along(dat)/n), function(x) sum(x == 'g'))
```

For example, for this vector of length 33 we divide data into interval of 11.

```
dat <- c("t", "a", "t", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "g", "a", "c", "g", 
"a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "a", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", 
"c", "a", "g", "g", "g", "t", "a", "t")

n <- 11
result <- tapply(dat, ceiling(seq_along(dat)/n), function(x) sum(x == 'g'))
result

#1 2 3 
#1 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowsum` with `gl` in `base R`

```
rowsum(+(dat == 'g'), as.integer(gl(length(dat), n, length(dat))))
```

#### data

```
dat <- c("t", "a", "t", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "g", "a", "c", "g", 
"a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "a", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", 
"c", "a", "g", "g", "g", "t", "a", "t")

n <- 11
```